# How do I install 3 zones on a Triangle Tube Challenger Solo cc125 boiler?

Tags: hvac

I bought a Triangle Tube Challenger Solo cc125 boiler and the installation instructions shows multiple zones. However, I can only see one set of thermostat terminals in the on-board wiring. Do I have to add zone controls to use three circulator pumps and three thermostats?

Answer (score 0):

For a multiple zone installation, each zone will require a thermostat in that zone to control a zone valve with an end switch to turn the boiler on/off or a thermostat to control the boiler and each pump. each pump will have to be coupled with a flow control valve. d george

Comment: In some system, the pumps themselves act as zone control, without explicit valves controlled by the thermostats.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of pump switching relay to control multiple zones. [This](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/manuals/1351150925280/85270_PROD_FILE.pdf) Taco switching relay should be what you need. They make all types of zone controls. Check pages 37-39 in the manual found [Here](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/Challenger%20Combi%20Manual%20-Install2.pdf) and it will show you a wiring diagram of how the manufacturer recommends its installed.